# When I attempt to run my .jar, I get a no library in java.library.path exception

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, java.library.path

I've looked through a number of posts, and tried what I've found to little success. Here's the setup:

I wrote a program in Java, worked alright, but we needed to switch cameras. This camera is Twain compatible (yuck). I rewrote the program (pretty simple), using JTwain, and it runs just fine in netbeans. I built it, and it runs just fine on my computer. However, when I try and transfer the .jar (and companion library etc.), it runs fine until it needs to take an image, then I get the error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no aspireJTwain in Java.library.path.

I've tried bringing the base twain package over, adding the system environmental variables, checking the java distribution. I can run the JTwain test file (to make sure you have JTwain and everything is hunky dory).

If someone could please lend a hand, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: What about building a "fat jar", see [How to build a fat jar using Netbeans](http://arunasujith.blogspot.de/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html).

Comment: I made a fat jar, but received the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check to make sure that you have followed the directions from the [The Java Developer's Guide to JTwain v9](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/AspriseJTwain-DevGuide.pdf).

**6.3 Software Packaging and Distribution**

> There are two files about JTwain you need to distribute along with
>   your own binary  code. One is JTwain.jar, which is like any other java
>   library, you can just copy it and put  it in the class path. The other
>   one is AspriseJTwain.dll, the native library. There are  many ways to
>   'install' this dll file, you can:   Add the folder containing the
>   native library to the system path, or  Copy the native library to
>   jre/bin directory – 'install' the library to the JVM, or  Copy the
>   native library to a specific location, e.g. C:\AspriseJTwain.dll,
>   before calling  SourceManage.instance(), call: 
>   SourceManage.setLibraryPath(“ C:\AspriseJTwain.dll ”);

Comment: I can indeed confirm that both computers followed the Developer's guide. In particular, I copied the folder over (containing all JTwain files), and added the file references to the environmental variables.

Comment: Have you included the `jid.jar` in the project?

Comment: I don't know what jid.jar is. Sorry.

Comment: I added the .dll to the /bin, and that worked. I don't know why adding a system path was insufficient.